# How can I able to display content in inventory seperated by commas in vue js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

My json data is

```
{ "status": true,
  "data": {
    "pid": 9,
    "Name": "Asok",
    "services": "3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6",
    "inventory": ["specs", " Testing", "Lens", "Doctors", "Surgeon", "Medicines"]
  }
}
```

Now I am using html as

```
<div v-for="inv in data.inventory">{{inv}}</div>
```

When I do this way, the data is printing downwards.. I need to display data seperated by commmas in a row??

Comment: {{inv.join(',')}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`div` is a block element so use a inline one, like `span`. As for commas, add it on all elements except the last one, for example:

```
<div>
   <span v-for="inv, index in data.inventory" v-if="index != data.inventory.length - 1">{{inv}},</span>
   <span v-else>{{inv}}</span>
</div>
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/22vc7f36/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by using span instead of div like

```
<span v-for="inv in data.inventory">{{inv}}, </span>
```

Unfortunately, you will end up with a trailing comma :-/

Maybe this is one of those cases where you should do some JS-preprocessing and keep the template simple, like:

```
<div>{{data.inventory.join(', ')}}</div>
```

This will solve the trailing comma problem without much effort.

Answer (score 0):

Your tag's `display` must be appropriate, for `div` it is a `block`, means that it will get the whole width of the row. So the next element will be placed under it. Instead of `div` you can use `span` tag to by default set the values after each other. Or you need to change the `display` property of current `div` element.

```
<div>
   <span v-for="inv in data.inventory">{{inv}}</span>
</div>
```

Let me show the examples with jQuery, not vue.js, but the logic is the same, its not the vue's or jquery-s problem.

```js
const obj = { "status": true,
  "data": {
    "pid": 9,
    "Name": "Asok",
    "services": "3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6",
    "inventory": ["specs", " Testing", "Lens", "Doctors", "Surgeon", "Medicines"]
  }
};

let str = '';

obj.data.inventory.forEach(ivt => {
  str += `<div>${ivt}</div>`;
});

$('#myFirstDiv').html(str);
str = '';

obj.data.inventory.forEach(ivt => {
  str += `<span>${ivt}</span>`;
});

$('#mySecondDiv').html(str);
str = '';

obj.data.inventory.forEach(ivt => {
  str += `<div class='inline-block'>${ivt}</div>`;
});

$('#myThirdDiv').html(str);
```

```css
div.inline-block {
   display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
With divs
<div id='myFirstDiv'>

</div>
<br/>
With spans
<div id='mySecondDiv'>

</div>
<br/>
With changed display
<div id='myThirdDiv'>

</div>
```